# Wrong connection strings returned

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-config

I've written a WCF service application.
When the project is generated, visual studio creates 3 web config files.

I've finished the project and to date I've been using a hard coded connection string within my GetOpenConnection() function, so I now want to move the connection string to the web.config files.

The following call returns null.
    ConnectionStringSettings csSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PulseWcfConnectionString"];

When I run the following code it doesn't return the string set in my web.debug.config file.

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count; idx++)
  Debug.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[idx].ConnectionString);
```

it returns the following 2 items, 2nd one is an empty string. I don't recognise the first line, maybe it's a default one?

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
""
```

What am I missing please?

My web.debug.config contains the following which should be for a local sql server instance

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="PulseWcfConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=WIN8-CLAIRE\SQLSRVDEV2008;Initial 
    Catalog=gcll;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

For now my web.release.config contains the same thing (it's being published to it's destination tomorrow so I'll change the details for it then)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="PulseWcfConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=WIN8-CLAIRE\SQLSRVDEV2008;Initial 
    Catalog=gcll;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name  ="pulse.smartcentre.wcf.service.app.PulseWebService"
               behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:52478/Design_Time_Addresses/pulse.smartcentre.wcf.service.app/PulseWebService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="pulse.smartcentre.wcf.service.app.IPulseWebService">

          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

      </service>
    </services>

    <!-- CNH -->
    <bindings>

      <!-- Secure binding (to use) -->
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true" transactionFlow="true">
          <readerQuotas
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxDepth="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>


    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>

          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you find out how to remove the wrongly added default connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the transformation files, you need to add the transformation property, and specify what you would like to do, Insert, Remove, Replace...

I use to put the local connection in the master web.config and then transform it in the Release configuration, by Replacing the attributes of the defined connection string.

Check this article: [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Project Deployment Using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)

If you want to use your way, just add `xdt:Transform="Insert"` in the `<add>` node.

You can test your transformation using this web tester: [Web.config Transformation Tester](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/)